# Mutually exclusive fixtures?

Tags: python, pytest

I have two mutually exclusive data fixtures, each required by a different test:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def testdata1(request, conn):
    savepoint = conn.begin_nested()
    request.addfinalizer(savepoint.rollback())
    # load dataset 1

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def testdata2(request, conn):
    savepoint = conn.begin_nested()
    request.addfinalizer(savepoint.rollback())
    # load dataset 2
```

While these work independently, the testdata1 fixture is not torn down before running my test that requires testdata2. Is there any way I can ensure that fixtures not required for a test are not active during that test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specify the scope as 'session' for both, both will remain active until the end of all of the tests.
You should specify tighter scope.
I think I understand what you want, but I don't think it's realistic to expect pytest to do it.

Something like:

```
testdata1()
test_that_uses_testdata1()
testdata1_finalizer()
test_data2()
test_that_uses_testdata2()
test_something_else()
testdata2_finalizer()
testdata1()
test_something_else_that_uses_testdata1()
testdata1_finalizer()
```

This really seems like a lot to expect of a test system. :)

Comment: Thanks. Guess it's just one of those differences between zope.testrunner [layers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.testrunner#layers) and pytest fixtures.